# Eigenvalues of symmetric matrices associated to posets

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, posets

For a finite connected poset $P$ define the Cartan matrix $C$ as the matrix with entries $c_{i,j}=1$ if $i \leq j$ and $c_{i,j}=0$ else, where $i,j\in P$.
Define the Frobenius-Cartan matrix of $P$ as $U=C+C^T$, which is a symmetric matrix. In the Boolean case this is studied in [Factorisation of a polynomial from the Boolean algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369515/factorisation-of-a-polynomial-from-the-boolean-algebra) .

> Question 1: Is it true that the number of positive eigenvalues of $U$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is larger than or equal than the number of negative eigenvalues?

This is true for posets with at most $n=7$ points and for bounded posets this is true until $n=9$.

Do the eigenvalues (and their signs) have a combinatorial interpretation?

> Question 2: What are the posets $P$ such that $U$ has a non-zero fixed point, that is $Ux=x$?

This class of posets contains all bounded posets (posets with a global maximum and minimum) where one can use $x=[1,0,....,0,-1]$.

> Question 3: Is there a characterisation when $U$ is positive (semi)definit?

There are surprisingly many such posets. There are even posets where all eigenvalues are integers (I wonder whether they can be classified, they seem to be extremely rare).

Comment: What you can the Cartan matrix is the zeta function in combinatorics

Comment: The fixed point in Question 2 is required to be nonzero, right?

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes, thanks.

Comment: Equivalently, you are looking at the spectrum, with each eigenvalue increased by 2, of (the adjacency matrix of) a comparability graph. One can look at your questions for more general graphs, such as perfect graphs. Note also that your question (1) is affirmative for posets with no 3-element chain since the comparability graph is bipartite, so its spectrum (before adding 2 to the eigenvalues) is symmetric about 0.

Comment: Note that $U$ is positive semidefinite (respectively, positive definite) if and only if the least eigenvalue of the comparability graph of $P$ is $\geq -2$ (respectively, $>-2$). All graphs with least eigenvalue $-2$ or greater than $-2$ have been classified. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379515003651. In principle one can go through this classification and see which ones are comparability graphs.