# Kernel of a matrix and the Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, catalan-numbers

Let $B_n$ denote the Boolean lattice of a set with $n \geq 2$ elements and $C_n$ the matrix with entries $c_{i,j}=1$ if $i \leq j$ and $c_{i,j}=0$ else, where $i,j\in B_n$.

Let $M_n:=C_n+C_n^T$ (this is also the Cartan matrix of a certain Frobenius algebra associated to $B_n$), which is a symmetric matrix. Thus geometric and algebraic multiplicity should coincide. Let $I$ denote the identity matrix.

> Question: Is there a bijective proof that for $n$ even (odd) we have that the basis of the kernel of $M_n - 2 I$ ($M_n-3 I$) is enumerated by the Catalan numbers?

This is true for $n \leq 15$.

(see also [Factorisation of a polynomial from the Boolean algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369515/factorisation-of-a-polynomial-from-the-boolean-algebra) )

Here a bijective proof asks for a bijection of a basis of the kernel to known combinatorial objects that are enumerated by the Catalan numbers.

For example for $n=6$, the kernel has dimension 5 and basis vectors are given by

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

I was not able to see a pattern so far for a nice basis of the kernel as the vectors are so big for larger n.

For example for $n=2$, $C_2$ is given by
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &1\\
0 & 0 & 1 &1\\
0 & 0 & 0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $M_2$ is given by
$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 &1\\
1 & 0 & 2 &1\\
1 & 1 & 1 &2\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Instead of "basis of kernel of $M_n-2I_n$" you can say "basis of $2$-eigenspace of $M_n$", right?

Comment: @SamHopkins Of course.

Comment: Mare, If I understand you correctly, then $M_n$ is the square-matrix of size $2^n\times 2^n$ with rows and columns indexed by all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with a coefficient $1$ if the rowset is included in the columnset and $0$ otherwise? By the way, your set of eigenvectors lacks (a short) description of the underlying basis.

Comment: @RolandBacher Not really. I included an example at the end of my post for clarity. (coefficients 2 appear in each diagonal).

Comment: Sorry, my description is for $C_n$.

Comment: @RolandBacher Yes, $i \leq j$ just means that $i$ is a subset of $j$ and the matrix is a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix.

Comment: How did you check this up to $n=15$?

Comment: @RolandBacher With Sage. Took some weeks.

Comment: By the way, I think you get the same Catalan number for an odd and an even dimension (since Catalan numbers grow almost like powers of $4$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128158/discussion-between-roland-bacher-and-mare).

Comment: Observation: relations in the kernel only involve sets of cardinalities $k-1$ and $k$ for $n=2k-1$ and sets of cardinality $k$ for $n=2k$. This might be easier to prove as the first step, and might bring you close to Catalan numbers...

Comment: To seek for patterns, here are examples. For $n=5$, one basis is$$\begin{array}{l}x_{12}-x_{13}-x_{25}+x_{35}+x_{124}-x_{134}-x_{245}+x_{345}\\x_{13}-x_{15}-x_{34}+x_{45}+x_{123}-x_{125}-x_{234}+x_{245}\\x_{14}-x_{15}-x_{34}+x_{35}+x_{124}-x_{125}-x_{234}+x_{235}\\x_{23}-x_{25}-x_{34}+x_{45}+x_{123}-x_{125}-x_{134}+x_{145}\\x_{24}-x_{25}-x_{34}+x_{35}+x_{124}-x_{125}-x_{134}+x_{135}\end{array}$$

Comment: and for $n=6$,$$\begin{array}{l}x_{123}-x_{124}-x_{136}+x_{146}-x_{235}+x_{245}+x_{356}-x_{456}\\x_{124}-x_{126}-x_{145}+x_{156}-x_{234}+x_{236}+x_{345}-x_{356}\\x_{125}-x_{126}-x_{145}+x_{146}-x_{235}+x_{236}+x_{345}-x_{346}\\x_{134}-x_{136}-x_{145}+x_{156}-x_{234}+x_{236}+x_{245}-x_{256}\\x_{135}-x_{136}-x_{145}+x_{146}-x_{235}+x_{236}+x_{245}-x_{246}\end{array}$$

Comment: @Mare You ask for a bijective proof, but do you have a non-bijective proof?

Comment: @TimothyChow No. A nonbijective proof is of course also interesting.

Comment: Another observation: the ($\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-) dimension of the kernel of $M_n  \bmod 2$ seems to be $\frac{2^n+2}{3}$ for even $n$ and
$\frac{2^n+1}{3}$ for odd $n$.

Answer (score 6):

Another suggestion: let $A_{2n}=M_{2n}-2I$ ($I$=identity matrix), so we are
interested in $\ker A_{2n}$. Let $V$ be the vector space on which $A_{2n}$
acts, so we can regard $V$ as having a basis consisting of all subsets
of $[2n]=\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$. Thus $V$ has a grading $V_0\oplus
V_1\oplus\cdots \oplus V_{2n}$, where $V_i$ has a basis consisting of all
$i$-element subsets of $[2n]$. The symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$
acts on $V$ and preserves the grading. Write $M_\lambda$ for the
irreducible $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$-module indexed by the partition $\lambda$
of $2n$. Then (as is well-known) $V_i$ decomposes as $M_{(2n)}\oplus
M_{(2n-1,1)} \oplus \cdots\oplus M_{(2n-i,i)}$ for $0\leq i\leq n$,
and $V_i\cong V_{2n-i}$ (as $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$-modules).

Assuming that $\dim\ker A_{2n}=C_n$, it is natural to conjecture that
as an $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$-module, $\ker A_{2n}$ is isomorphic to the
irreducible module $M_{(n,n)}$. The operator
$\frac{1}{(2n)!}\sum_{w\in\mathfrak{S}_{2n}}\chi^{(n,n)}(w)w$ will
then project $V_n$ to $\ker A_{2n}$. Here $\chi^{(n,n)}$ is the
irreducible character of $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$ indexed by the partition
$(n,n)$.  There is something similar for $M_{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Only a suggestion: This smells of the Temperley-Lieb algebra. Eigenspaces of $M_n$ are invariant under the obvious action of the symmetric group $S_n$. The $2-$eigenspace of $M_n$ is thus a decomposition of irreps of $S_n$. The sum of squared dimensions for irreps with Young diagrams having at most $2$ rows of $S_n$ is the $n-$th Catalan number.

The relation is probably not completely straightforward: Since Catalan numbers grow like $4^nn^{-3/2}$ (up to a constant), your matrix $M_n$ should roughly involve the Temperley Lie algebra of $S_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$.

In any case, the determination of the involved irreps of $S_n$ gives probably an indication of what is going on.